# Looking for help in designing load tests

Tags: java, performance, jmeter, rabbitmq, load-testing

I've been given the task of load testing the software my team designs and builds. It is a Java web app that acts as an API to all the other applications my company makes.

This is a rough outline of the system:

```
1) Application 1 needs information from the database.

2) App 1 produces a request to a rabbit exchange (routing key for the queue that is consumed by the tool I'm testing). 

3) My tool consumes the RabbitMQ queue that App1 pushed to

4) My tool executes the request sent from App1 via the Rabbit queue

5) My tool then sends the response back to App 1 via a Rabbit Exchange/Reply Queue. 

6) App 1 then consumes from the reply queue and handles the response
```

This is a very low level view as there are a lot of instances of each app that is publishing to and consuming the queue.

I've never load tested anything before so I'm new to the concepts and tools available.

Right now I'm using jMeter to initiate the calls and consume the replies (and I have it operating just like App 1 in the examples, it calls via rabbit and consumes the replies).

Here are my questions:

```
1) Is this a viable way to load test? Should I be testing the capacity of the server directly or should I continue going through rabbit since it's a closer to production use case?

2) What is the best way to adjust my rate of production? I've tried doing some throttling via jMeter but when I look at the rabbit graphs the publish rate seems to fluctuate wildly. Example: I tell jMeter to publish at 1000 messages/sec and the graph on the rabbit dashboard goes from 500/sec to 3000/sec. I don't feel like I can accurately get an idea of what we can handle if I can reliably adjust the rate.
```

My plan was:

```
1) Find the rate at which my application can't pick things off the queue fast enough. (where the rate of publishing to the queue becomes faster than my application can consume them). 

2) Once I know the fastest I can send stuff to the queue I can check the responses for error rate and processing time.
```

I was thinking that by doing this I can figure out what the maximum rate we can publish to the queue while still being within an acceptable error rate and  an idea of what the turnaround time will be.

Is there anything else I should be looking for? Any "rules" of load testing I should know about in order to be successful in this?

Thanks!

Comment: Load testing is complex, not easy to dissect in a comment (but no time for longer answer).  One thing to keep in mind is you need to have clear objectives of what you are trying to demonstrate.  Are you trying to see if the server can handle a specific load (i.e. 3000 transactions/second) or what is the max. load the server can handle?  If you aim at one goal but test something else, the results you get will not allow you to reach a conclusion (based on collected data)

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion you should consider following things,

1. For Load testing of any complex system(which includes multiple components), divide the load testing as per components (App1, Rabbit queue, producer, consumer).

   Reason behind this is in one test you cannot get the bottleneck in the system or it will lead to incorrect results.
2. In my team we have had such assignment (publisher - consumer model) once. There is no rule which says for load testing you **must** use any load testing tool. A simple java code which can act as load generator (Publisher) and simple java code which consumes the load (Consumer) will be enough for load testing.
3. JMeter is a good option (free, scalable, reliable, known in Industry) but you can check LoadRunner, Neoload etc.

IMHO, You should seperate the components and test them individually which will help you to find answers like what is max consumer rate and what is max publisher rate. A simple java code can do that for you. You dont need JMeter requests for that. This way you can have more control on rate of production as well as rate of consumption.

Yes your plan was correct, Find the max. rates possible rates at which publisher and consumer can give you max. system throughput. While doing this, have an eye on system utilization also.

Finally when you get measurements of stable system, you can go for 2 options,

```
1. Stress test (when system breaks)
2. Tune the system to improve the performance and repeat the cycle for new measurements.
```

I hope some confusion is clear now :)